# Read and write in a concurrenthashmap

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrenthashmap

I have doubt understanding concurrenthashmap . If a section of conc hashmap is locked up by a writer thread then is it possible for a reader thread to read the same section of hashmap map simultaneously ? or does it need the lock to be released from the writer thread ?

Comment: Are you asking about *using* a ConcurrentHashMap or about how it is *implemented*?

Comment: Read the first two paragraphs of the [`ConcurrentHashMap` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). Actually, read all of it.

Comment: i read the concurrency level should not be too big as it might waste space and time. Please elaborate this . what is wrong if we have larger number of segments that can be locked what is the performance impact ?

Comment: @jayendrabhatt This is a new question and should be posted as such.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code of [ConcurrentHashMap.get()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#ConcurrentHashMap.Segment.get%28java.lang.Object%2Cint%29) then you can easily understand it.

**No lock** is required while reading from concurrent map but if the value is `null` it checks again under [readValueUnderLock](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#ConcurrentHashMap.Segment.readValueUnderLock%28java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.HashEntry%29)

```
    get(Object key, int hash) {
         if (count != 0) { // read-volatile
             HashEntry<K,V> e = getFirst(hash);
             while (e != null) {
                 if (e.hash == hash && key.equals(e.key)) {
                     V v = e.value;
                     if (v != null)
                         return v;
                     return readValueUnderLock(e); // recheck
                 }
                 e = e.next;
             }
         }
         return null;
     }

    readValueUnderLock(HashEntry<K,V> e) {
         lock();
         try {
             return e.value;
         } finally {
             unlock();
         }
     }
```

Look at the [ConcurrentHashMap.put()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#ConcurrentHashMap.Segment.put%28java.lang.Object%2Cint%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cboolean%29) method as well that first calls `lock()` and finally calls `unlock()`

```
    put(K key, int hash, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent) {
         lock();
         try {
            ...
         } finally {
             unlock();
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

No lock is required for reading.Locks are required to update the map.